# 3D plot with Region seems inaccurate

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[x/Max[y,z] == Max[y,z]/Abs[y-z] && x+y+z == 1,{x,y,z}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.001, 0.999}, {0.001, 0.999}, {0.001, 0.999}}]
```

produces the following graph with gaps and incorrect linear segments: [image]

Any advice would be very welcome.

Comment: Does `DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[x/Max[y, z] == Max[y, z]/Abs[y - z] && x + y + z == 1, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.001}, Method -> "MarchingCubes"]` do what you want?

Comment: Perfect, thank you!